# c++ string compare operator > produces different outputs depending on how two strings are compared

Tags: c++

Below code produces different results:

1. Initialize and assign values to string variables to compare.

string d = "d";
string abc = "abc";

d > abc evaluates to true.

2. Compare strings.
   "d" > "abc" evaluates to false.

How do they produce different outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"d"` is not a `std::string`. It is a `const char *`. As such, when you do `string d = "d"`, you set a string to the `const char *` of `{'d', '\0'}`. Then when you compare it, the `std::string operator>` is used instead of the version for a `const char *`.

Comment: `"d"` is actually a `const char[2]`, although if used as operand of `>` it is converted to `const char *` at that time.